# have a nice representation of a string from a double

Tags: c++, string, double

I have a double 1.4291400000000001
I want to have a string representation of that double.

What is the best/standard way to get 1.42914

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What about:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision( N ) << double_number;
// ss.str() gives you the string
```

Comment: so we absolutely need to know N, there is no magical solution.

Answer (score 2):

It's not guaranteed to have a `double` to have exactly this value : `1.4291400000000001`.  It could be a little greater than that or little smaller than that. Much less like to be exactly that.

After this fact, I can say that there is no best way to get `1.42914` from that. You might get `1.42913` instead, as the actual double value might be : `1.4291399999999999` instead of the above value.

Read this: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: yes but, in both case 1.421399999 and 1.429140000001 we want 1.4214 normally.. so maybe there is a nice way to do that

Comment: @Guillaume07: Sure there is, `setprecision(4)`.